# How to Scroll UICollectionViewCell using UISlider in Left or Right

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uislider

Hi I have a CollectionView and CollectionViewCell that the data filled by the server, outside the collectionView i have a UISlider. I want when i drag the UISlider in Right side to scroll the collectionViewCell to right side and when i drag the UISlider in Left side to scroll to right side! Any Help ?

Comment: Map `UISlider`'s progress and `CollectionView`'s offset together.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the content offset of your collection view depending on the value of the slider.

```
@IBAction func sliderAction(_ sender: UISlider) {
    myCollectionView.contentOffset.y += sender.value // here, use logic to handle left / right direction
}
```